# Groupby with sum over columns to get frequency of each item using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the frequency of days grouped by its ID. So I would like to know:

1. The total number of days for each ID and
2. the frequency of each day per ID.

So it should be look like this:

[image: my data]

On top of that I tried the following:

```
number = data.groupby(by=['ID, Date_Time']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

but this on gives me a different data frame that I can't add it to the original on "data".

Comment: Please provide a sample of reproducible code to include the input, don't paste images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a simple data sample as you have only provided a screenshot, you need to convert the date to datetime format and then group according to id and `pd.Grouper` according to distinct days (D). For total all you need is `groupby` and transform the count of each group.

```
data = [[1, "2010-01-01 12:21:46"],[1, "2010-01-01 12:22:46"],[1, "2010-04-02 12:21:46"],[1, "2010-06-06 12:21:46"],[2, "2010-06-06 12:21:46"],[2, "2010-06-06 19:21:46"],[2, "2010-09-06 12:21:46"]]

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=("id","date_"))
df['date_']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['freq'] = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key='date_', freq='D')])['id'].transform('count')
df['total'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('count')
```

Final ouptput will look like this:

> ```
>    id               date_  freq  total
> 0   1 2010-01-01 12:21:46     2      4
> 1   1 2010-01-01 12:22:46     2      4
> 2   1 2010-04-02 12:21:46     1      4
> 3   1 2010-06-06 12:21:46     1      4
> 4   2 2010-06-06 12:21:46     2      3
> 5   2 2010-06-06 19:21:46     2      3
> 6   2 2010-09-06 12:21:46     1      3
> ```